# Detecting when UITableViewCells have completely finished

Tags: ios, memory-management, xamarin.ios

I am attempting to structure my application using the MVVM pattern. Therefor I have ViewModels that raise events when data changes, and the UI is expected to react to those events and update the visible UI controls.

I have a derived `UITableViewCell` that gets initialized with a certain ViewModel every time a new cell is created or dequeued (very similar to [miguel's example here](http://tirania.org/monomac/archive/2011/Jan-18.html)). One main difference being part of the initializing relies on subscribing to an event of the ViewModel. This creates a reference from the long lived ViewModel to this specific cell, holding it in memory for the lifetime of the ViewModel. When the cell is re-used, the old subscription is cleaned up and a new one created to the new ViewModel, that works fine.

However the problem is there doesn't seem to be any opportunity to clean up the last subscription once the cell is completely finished, which means it is held in memory for the lifetime of the ViewModel (much longer than I want it to be).
'Completely finished' depends on the VC hierarchy, but in this case the derived DialogViewController that contains the TableView with custom cells has been popped from the `UINavigationController` stack and has been disposed.

`willMoveToSuperview` is never called (I was hoping it would be with 'null' being passed in).
`removeFromSuperview` is never called.
Dispose on each cell is never called.
Disposing of the UITableViewController doesn't dispose each cell.
Disposing of the TableView within the controller doesn't even dispose each cell.

The only way I can manually dispose each cell (and hence clean up subscriptions) is by enumerating the cells manually myself in each of my derived `UIViewControllers`, something I want to avoid.

Has anyone has similar troubles like this? I cant be the first using the MVVM pattern with UITableViewCells.
Is this a bug with the Dispose pattern in the base MonoTouch UIKit wrappers?

EDIT:
Here is cut-down version of one of the custom `UITableViewCells`. Note I'm taking a pragmatic approach where I explicitly subscribe to events of properties I know may change, not a full MVVM bind every property to the UI. So my binding code consists of just standard event subscriptions:

```
public class MyCustomCell : UITableViewCell
{
    private InvoiceViewModel currentViewModel;

    private readonly UILabel label1;
    private readonly UILabel label2;

    public MyCustomCell(NSString reuseId)
        : base(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseId)
    {
        Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;
        SelectedBackgroundView = new UIView()
        {
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(235,235,235),
        };

        label1 = new UILabel();
        ContentView.Add(label1);
        // The rest of the UI setup...
    }

    public void Update(MyViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if ( currentViewModel == viewModel )
            return;

        if ( currentViewModel != null )
        {
            // Cleanup old bindings.
            currentViewModel.UnacknowledgedRemindersChanged -= HandleNotificationsChanged;
        }

        currentViewModel = viewModel;

        if ( viewModel != null )
        {
            viewModel.UnacknowledgedRemindersChanged += HandleNotificationsChanged;

            label1.Text = viewModel.SomeProperty;
            // Update the rest of the UI with the current view model.
        }
    }

    private void HandleNotificationsChanged()
    {
        // Event can fire on background thread.
        BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            // Relevant UI updates go here.
        });
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // Unsubscribes from ViewModel events.
        Update(null);
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

And my derived MT.D element class has a 1:1 element:viewmodel, so the `GetCell` method looks like this:

```
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tv)
    {
        var cell = (MyCustomCell) tv.DequeueReusableCell(key);
        if (cell == null)
            cell = new MyCustomCell(key);

        cell.Update(viewModel);
        return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're definitely not the first to do Mvvm table cells with MonoTouch.

I've blogged about it recently at http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/uitableviewcell-using-xib-editor.html

Before that there have been projects at NDC (search for "Flights of Norway") and there was a long running Mvvm project built on top of MonoTouch.Dialog.

---

In MvvmCross apps, we use tables bound to ObservableCollections and to other IList classes a lot.

Within these we generally don't hit many problems with left-living references, but that's because we generally don't encourage people to use long-living ViewModels - we try to create a new instance of ViewModel data to go with each View. However, I do understand that that may not be suitable for all appications.

---

When an Mvx user finds themselves with this type of problem, then some of the approaches we've tried are:

- in iOS5 we did use the ViewDidUnload method to clean up bindings - but obviously that is now gone in iOS6.
- depending on the UI presentation style (modal, splitview, navigationcontroller, popup, etc) we have tried manually detecting when views are 'popped' and using this to clear up bindings
- again depending on the UI presentation style, we have tried using the ViewDidAppear, ViewDidDisappear events to add and tidy up the bindings
- for all UIKit classes with data-binding we've always used Dispose as an extra place to try to clear up bindings
- we've looked at using WeakReferences (especially from the ViewModel to the View) in order to get around the issues where the UIKit objects are owned by both iOS/ObjC and by MonoTouch/.Net - these problems are particularly hard to debug.
- this weak reference code is likely to be one the key changes in the next release.

An example discussion about this (in Droid rather than in Touch) is on https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/17

---

I'm sorry I can't offer you any specific advice at this moment. If you post some more example code about how you are creating and storing your bindings, I might be able to help more - but I can't really visualise what bindings you are creating right now.

I've got a few more links I'll add to this answer later - on mobile at present - too hard to add them here!

---

**Update** - for some more explanation on the WeakReference ideas, this is where we're heading now in v3 for MvvmCross - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/tree/vNextDialog/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding/WeakSubscription - basically the idea is to use disposable weakreference event subscriptions - which won't keep the UIKit objects in RAM. It's not properly tested code yet. When it is, then I'll blog and talk about it more fully!

Comment: Thanks Stuart! I've edited my question to include some example code. I think I'm going to go with a stricter ViewModel lifecycle approach for now. In regards to your weak delegate event approach: proceed with caution. We did this a while back, and it's an extra complication all developers have to keep in their heads. e.g. Subscribing to these events with a lambda subscription with closures produces very hard to track down bugs as nothing holds the backing closure instance in memory and so it is GCed at some point in the future, effectively randomly unsubscribing your event handler.

Comment: Thanks @Tyson - I've been there recently with lambdas on a Messenger implementation :) Caution engaged (that's why that thread has been open 8 months)

Comment: Just adding a cross reference to more WeakReference stuff http://stackoverflow.com/a/14734264/373321