# Weak referencing in MvvmCross with Action<T>

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

As previously detailed in some MvvmCross videos (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYu_9rcAJU4&feature=youtu.be&t=33m41s)

I am trying to remove strong references from my viewmodel to my views.

Having implemented WeakSubscribe() where PropertyChanged += has been used I have now come across some scenarios where I am using Action to allow the view to observe. I assume this will lead to potential memory leaks again, so attempting to erradicate.

However - WeakReference works on the basis of hooking to an INotifyPropertyChanged source:

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/162a816d148df224df0b8f635aeafe30c0910de9/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/WeakSubscription/MvxWeakSubscriptionExtensionMethods.cs

So should I be refactoring my code to ditch Action and to be firing via PropertyChanged to be able to inform the view via a weak reference?

Here is some sample code just for reference - of the current strongly referenced architecture.

**ViewModel**

```
    public event Action Loaded;
    public HomeViewModel()
    {
        FeaturedProductCategoryViewModel = new FeaturedProductsViewModel();
        FeaturedProductCategoryViewModel.OnPopulated += () =>
        {
            if (Loaded != null) Loaded();
        };
    }
```

**View**

```
    public MainHomePageView()
        : base(GetNibName("MainHomePageView"), null)
    {
        this.EnableLandscapeRotation ();
    }

    protected override void ViewJustLoaded()
    {
        this.ViewModel.Loaded += LoadControls;
    }

    void LoadControls()
    {
        //load controls when view model is populated
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The driving mentality behind MvvmCross' weak reference approach is that ViewModels should never have references to Views - as if they do then it can lead to Views having references to their containing Views.

Some background to this is in https://stackoverflow.com/a/14734264/373321

In the case of an event like `Loaded` with it's somewhat unorthodox `Action` type, I think this can be subscribed to using a new `WeakSubscribe` extension method and handler.

Alternatively you could change `Loaded` to an `EventHandler` type and then use the `WeakSubscribe(this EventInfo eventInfo, ...` extension method:

```
  // ViewModel - define event
  public event EventHandler Loaded;

  // View - subscription
  IDisposable _subscription;

  // View - in ViewDidLoad
  _subscription = typeof(HomeViewModel)
                      .GetEvent("Loaded")
                      .WeakSubscribe(this.ViewModel, OnLoaded);

  // View - event handler
  public void OnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     LoadControls();
  }
```

Comment: You write "ViewModels should never have references to Views". But it is already the case here. So why would you use a WeakSomething ?

Comment: @Softlion - `this.ViewModel.Loaded += LoadControls;` in question created a strong reference inside the ViewModel, back to the View. Specifically, VM's Loaded event was given a strong reference to View.LoadControls. Here, this is replaced by `WeakSubscribe`.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve maybe, but when time to destroy the view comes, mvvmcross explicitely disposes the viewmodel. So there is no issue.

Comment: @Softlion - I don't disagree re mvvmcross. I was responding to your statement "But it is already the case here". I presumed "here" refers to the logic in the QUESTION, which this answer replaces with a use of mvvmcross. Hence avoiding an issue in the original question's logic. **If you meant that you would use mvvmcross differently, please show code you would use.**

Comment: Well mvvm cross managed both the view and the viewmodel and the navigation so it has all infos needed to manage the lifetime of viewmodel objects. If you manage this lifetime yourself that means something is not working right in mvvm cross.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better solution would be to have a bool property in the view model (Called IsBusy) then, when you start loading - set IsBusy to true.  When you finish loading - set it back to false; then in your View, use a mvvmcross property listener to act on the loading finishing

```
        listener = new MvxPropertyChangedListener(IncidentViewModel).Listen<bool>(
            () => IncidentViewModel.IsBusy,
            () =>
            {
                if (IncidentViewModel != null && !IncidentViewModel.IsBusy)
                {
                    LoadControls();
                }
            });
```